# Unity When button click show admob Interstitial

Tags: admob, interstitial

I want to add admob interstital ads, when button click show ads, after ads closed "Change Vehicle" menu
this is my "Change Vehicle" button code

```
            if( GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width - 270, 330, 240, 50), "Change Vehicle") )
        {
            selectScreen = true;
            objects[activeObjectIdx].GetComponent<CarControllerV2>().canControl = false;
            GetComponent<CamManager>().enabled = false;
            GetComponent<SmoothFollow>().enabled = false;
            GetComponent<MouseOrbit>().enabled = false;
            Camera.main.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(Camera.main.transform.rotation.x, 330, Camera.main.transform.rotation.z);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/interstitial), can save you a lot of trouble.

You basically have to create an interstitial ad by using you Ad Unit Id which you can create in the AdMob console.

```
this.interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
```

Then you need to create an AdRequest and use it to load an interstitial like this:

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
this.interstitial.LoadAd(request);
```

At this moment your interstitial is not yet on the screen. To do that you have to check that the ad is loaded and then call the Show method like:

```
  if (this.interstitial.IsLoaded()) {
    this.interstitial.Show();
  }
```

The takeaway here is that you should load your ad (LoadAd(request)) a while before deciding to show it so that the ad has enough time to actually load. So in your situation you can load an interstitial shortly after starting your app/game and call Show() when clicking the button.

Note that sometimes no ads are loaded because AdMob cannot provide one at the requested time (for various reasons). Also when you test your ads do it with TestAds as to not get your AdMob account suspended.

When it is time to hide the interstitial don't forget to call:

```
interstitial.Destroy();
```

There are also callbacks available for various events in the interstitial ad lifecycle and you can read all that in the documentation page provided.

Comment: Not like this, i want this, when "change car" button clicked show ads, after ads closed come car change menu

Comment: You should really read that documentation page. You can see there a OnAdClosed event that you can listen for and in that handler put your "show car change menu" code.